# What causes denormalized floating point numbers to arise and why can't they be just avoided as a rule?

Tags: floating-point

The de-normalized numbers are where the mantissa does not have an implicit 1. They are of the 0.f form where f is the mantissa stored in the floating point number.

What I understand so far is that denormal numbers are undesired. My question is, why can they arise during calculation and why not just avoid them in the first place since we have so much range in floating point numbers?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, why can they arise during calculation

*Denormal numbers*, better called [subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) are very useful in subtraction.

Consider the 2 smallest *normal* numbers.  What is their difference?

```
diff = smallest_normal_next - smallest_normal
```

With subnormal numbers, `diff` is non-zero<sup>*1</sup>.

Without subnormal numbers, `diff` is typically rounded to 0.0.

The helps avoid a whole class of problems that plagued early programing like:

```
if (a ≠ b) then // Prevent division by zero.
  d = c/(a-b)   // Fails to always prevent division by zero without subnormals.
endif
```

This gradual loss of precision of *subnormals* eases the math transition of small floating point *normal* numbers to 0.0.

---

<sup>*1</sup> The difference of any 2 *different* valued finite floating point values (normal or subnormal) is then non-zero.  Without subnormals, math risks a difference of 2 different values as zero - depending rounding.

Comment: I am not sure when such a scenario can arise. Lets put it another way, should an infitesimally small number be treated as zero for purpose of calculation anyway where division results in infinity and multiplication results in zero? Why both with these numbers if they create so much hassle? Just design the FPU so small numbers that are so small, just become actual value zero.

Comment: @quantum231 "I am not sure when such a scenario can arise." --> I am sure such situations arise.  "Just design the FPU so small numbers that are so small, just become actual value zero" --> that is what sub-normals do.  Values less than the smallest normal numbers are sub-normal and gradual lose precision as they become smaller and smaller, until eventually 0.0.